# How to sort by years?

Tags: php

```
$name = glob('*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);


for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
  if( substr($name[$i],0,1) != "_") {
    $shortname = substr($name[$i], 0, -4); //ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_2016 ...
    $bezyear = substr($shortname, 0, -4); // ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_ ...
    $rest = substr($shortname, -4); // 2016...
    $nazv = $rest."_".$bezyear; // 2016_ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_...

     natsort($nazv);

    $namenew = str_replace('_', ' ', $nazv);
    $namenew = ucwords($namenew); 
    echo "<tr>
        <td><a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'><img src='./img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' width='172px'></a><br/></td>
        <td><a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'><center>".$namenew."</center></a><br/></td>
    </tr>";



  }
}
```

The script prints the list as follows:

```
2017 Audi Q3
2016 Audi Q7
2017 Audi Q7 E Tron 2 Tfsi Quattro
2015 Audi R18 E-tron Quattro Racecar
2014 Audi R18 E Tron Quattro Lmp1 Racecar
2016 Audi R18 Racecar
2015 Audi R8 Competition
2016 Audi R8 Coupe V10 Plus Selection 24h
2016 Audi R8 E Tron
```

How to sort by years:

2017 Audi Q3

2017 Audi Q7 E Tron 2 Tfsi Quattro

2016 Audi Q7

2016 Audi R18 Racecar

2016 Audi R8 Coupe V10 Plus Selection 24h

2016 Audi R8 E Tron

2015 Audi R18 E-tron Quattro Racecar

2015 Audi R8 Competition

2014 Audi R18 E Tron Quattro Lmp1 Racecar

Used  natsort($nazv); - does not work...

Comment: Can you replace `$name = glob('*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);` - So that all of us can try out the code

Comment: First line `$name=` shoudl that be an array?? Cause it aint currently

Comment: `Warning: natsort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given`

Comment: You are sorting inside the loop? What do you think you are sorting

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: I sort $nazv - array

Comment: `$nazv` is not an array

Comment: You may find this tutorial on [debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) helpful.
 The link comes from stack overflow's [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and one of the suggestions is to turn on all warnings and pay attention to them (like @RiggsFolly pointed out)

Comment: Thing is you need to sort $name before you start manipulating it

Answer (score 1):

you can try more easily doing with one function

```
function my_sort($a,$b)
{

    preg_match('/\d{4}/',$a,$a1);
    preg_match('/\d{4}/',$b,$b1);


    if ($a1==$b1) return 0;
    return ($a1>$b1)?-1:1;
}

$names=array("ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_2016.php", "acura_cdx_2017.php", "acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013.php", "acura_mdx_2017.php", "acura_nsx_2016.php", "acura_nsx_2017.php", "acura_nsx__2016.php");

usort($names,"my_sort");

print_r($names);
```

Comment: the function is only to separate , if you use some library or something, but as the 1st anwer of Alexandar, you can do it in one line too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all cars in associative array (in your current loop), then sort it based on year with usort (outside the loop) and after that display the html (in a new loop). Something like that:

```
...
$cars = [];
for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
    ...

    $cars[] = [
        'year' => $bezyear,
        'name' => $name[$i],
        'namenew' => $namenew,
        'shortname' => $shortname,
    ];
}

usort($cars, function($car1, $car2) {
    return $car1['year'] - $car2['year'];
});

foreach ($cars as $car) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td><a target=_blank href='".$car['name']."'><img src='./img/_share/".$car['shortname']."_1.jpg' width='172px'></a><br/></td>
    <td><a target=_blank href='".$car['name']."'><center>".$car['namenew']."</center></a><br/></td>
</tr>";
}
```

Comment: `@Alexandar Mitsev` I described in more detail my steps